# What is the R script for the "isectpolyrst" from GME?

Tags: r, arcgis, arcmap

I'm trying to summarize raster cell values in overlapping polygons in ArcMap. This can be done in Geospatial Modelling Environment (GME), an extension for ArcMap. They have a command called isectpolyrst that calculates for values in overlapping polygons. My problem is, my version of ArcGIS (10.6.2), doesn't support the use of GME, so I can't use this function. I've heard that isectpolyrst can still accomplished in R Studio using R script, but I haven't found it anywhere.

I have a number of GPS points with 10 km buffers around them (these buffers overlap a lot). I'm trying to calculate proportions of different vegetation types within these buffer zones. I'm using ArcMap 10.6.2., and zonal statistics can't calculate for overlapping polygons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raster::extract` for that. As you seem entirely new to R, you will need to study it a bit first. You can start here: https://rspatial.org/